# TypeScript (v3.1.3): Aliasing a generically typed interface?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, typing

Here's what I need typescript to do.  Would save me an immense amount of coding.

```
interface Base<T,TReturn>
{
   x():TReturn<T>

   y<TResult>():TReturn<TResult>
}

interface A<T> extends Base<T,Array>
{
}

interface B<T> extends Base<T,List>
{
}
```

Is this possible?  How can I do this?

Basic overview, I need to have an interface structure, that I can define what the return type is with a given parameter.  Without the above possibility, I'm forced to write unique copies of the interface signature like so:

```
interface A<T,Array>
{
   x():Array<T>

   y<TResult>():Array<TResult>
}

interface B<T,List>
{
   x():List<T>

   y<TResult>():List<TResult>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to use generic in generic [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213). But without it you can do that. Fe: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Base%3CT%2CTReturn%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20x()%3A%20TReturn%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20y()%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%3CT%3E%20extends%20Base%3CT%2C%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%3CT%3E%20extends%20Base%3CT%2C%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20A%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fautocomplate%20works%20here%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20B%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fautocomplate%20works%20here%0D%0A%7D)